# Entity framework : how to generate a SQL Server model

Tags: c#, sql-server, model, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL Server with multiple databases.

I'm trying to build a "database browser" with Entity Framework 6.4.4 (in C#, ASP.NET MVC 5) that allows users to access any data stored on a particular SQL Server.

The problem is that we already have a huge amount of databases each containing as many tables and columns and it would really be a pain being forced to generate a model for every database by hand.

Therefore, I thought the entity framework would provide a way to generate a sort of "ServerModel", making it easier to handle multiple databases but also have them packed in a single generated model.

I would use such a model like this:

```
ServerModel sm = new ServerModel("Sql server name");

//list all databases
foreach(var db in sm.Databases) {} // or maybe sm.ToList() ?

//access specific database model and table
sm.MyDatabase.MyTable.ToList()
```

I couldn't find anyone trying to achieve this with Entity Framework online.

Is Entity Framework made for this?
Or should I start thinking my own solution?

And... does anyone have any?

Comment: Use GetSchema : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?force_isolation=true&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: I guess you'd create a class containing sqlConnection information and populate a List<System.Data.DataTable> ? Is there any way to generate such a class with EF ?

Comment: Pretty broad question. But maybe you should take a look at Sqlmetal which generates code for LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: Well I was just wondering if there was anything like ServerContext that we could have inherit from, the same way we inherit from DbContext and that would lead to some ServerModel class. I mean, imagine you have 1000 databases (that's just an example ^^) and you're asked to generate the model of every table contained in these databases. You're using visual studio and EF that helps you build your model with the ADO.NET template. What would you do to spare you the most amount of time considering you only know a way to generate one database model at a time ?

Comment: EF is an ORM tool that maps your **specific** database objects to concrete classes to simplify data access to **specific** objects and business rule implementation. If you are creating a tool that can access any kind table/run any SP in any database (like SSMS) why would you even consider EF? It will not help you with anything.

Comment: What you are looking for is something along the lines of [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Well, indeed, I considered dropping EF for something else... And I already have some ideas, but for the moment, EF is part of my requirements.

Comment: SMO might be a good choice if I was to drop EF !

Comment: Why do you need a c# class object?  You can simply put results into a DataSet/DataTable by using the SQLClient class to so a query like "Use DB1; Select * from table1".

Comment: Well, indeed, I think they're not required for the moment... let's assume that's more like a "challenge" I was asked (EF) ! But if it is not possible, your solution could be a good fit as well. This is why, in the first place, I was wondering if this was even possible using EF "only". Based on all your answers, it appears to be not possible (or just not made for such a use case...). I'll start building a custom solution and come back to share you my progress.